# CSS within HTML auto complete or suggestion in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, css, autocomplete

Is there a way to set Sublime Text to suggestion or autocomplete html classes like:

```
<div style="border: <suggestions here>"</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: By any chance did you get this plugin? I'm also looking for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be automatically enabled for HTML, according to http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/auto_complete.html.

You need to enter a < character first before the dropdown menu occurs. Then hit tab to select the highest ranked suggestion, or select it manually from the menu.

Comment: Doesn't work within style css inside html, like the example I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you need is to download the below package from Git Hub..give it a try..

https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete

Comment: I still don't get CSS sugestions inside the style tags after installing the plugin: http://imgur.com/YBsgLXl

Comment: have you installed from the link I provided? because whatever you have posted is something different @JoséJunior

Answer (score 0):

Install package from package control then install bootstrap autocomplete plugin
it will show all the suggestions in dropdown